# How to Pass a parameter to a method from NSTread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, nsthread

i am getting a string as parameter in an NSTread now i have to pass this string to next method so how can i do it? my code is given below:
calling method and passing an object

```
[self friendPic:user.userId];
```

my `NSTread` is this

```
-(void)friendPic:(NSString *)friendID{
    NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(getFriendPic) object:friendID];
    [thread start];
    [thread release];

}

-(void)getFriendPic:(NSString *)_friendID{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];



    NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.3softcanada.com/ipictures/Image%@.png",_friendID];

    NSLog(@"url is%@", str);
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];

    UIImage *theImage= [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData ];
    avatar.image = theImage;

    [pool release];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to replace `selector:@selector(getFriendPic)` with `selector:@selector(getFriendPic:)`. You missed a colon.