# Xcode objective-c How do I pass Multiple Arguments to a Function Using NSThread Ascynchrously

Tags: xcode, arguments, nsthread

I can't find any answers anywhere for this question and it should be simple.

I have a function:

```
void doSearch(NSURL *searchPathURL, NSArray *searchWords, NSTextView *textView){
...
}
```

I want to create an asynchronous thread to run the function above in the background and pass the function three arguments **of the data types specified** in the prototype above.  The closest example I found was supposed to handle one parameter see: [How to Pass a parameter to a method from NSTread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600081/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-method-from-nstread)

This does not apply to my needs.  How can I change the code in the example of the link above to get the job done?

Answer (score 0):

One parameter / argument could be also an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, for example

```
NSDictionary *arguments = @{@"searchPathURL" : searchPathURL, @"searchWords" : searchWords, @"textView" : textView};
```

the dictionary is one object and can be passed thru the object parameter

Comment: Thanks vadian, I used NSArray and it worked great.  I have run across another problem with the thread running out of memory which I created a new question titled "Xcode objective-c NSThread arguments".